# How can I set a keyboard shortcut to expand a wingpanel icon (ie the sound/music one)?

Tags: wingpanel, keyboard-shortcuts

As stated in title. I'd like to use a key combination or a macro key to open/close the sound icon in wingpanel, rather than clicking it each time. It seems like it should be trivial, but I can't find any examples of someone else doing it online.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom shortcut in settings under keyboard. You can use 'wingpanel --open-indicator={indicator}' to open a specific indicator. For sound it would be 'wingpanel --open-indicator=sound'

Comment: Thanks so much! I knew there must be some way to do it in bash but didn't know where to start. In case anyone else is looking for this for the same reasons I was, I ended up using `wingpanel --toggle-indicator={indicator}` so I could open/close without a mouse.